# Populate Mongo Database with Json file in Python Script from command Line

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, express

```
page = open("npm.json", "r")
parsed = json.loads(page.read())

for i in parsed["dependencies"]:
    collection.insert_one(i)
```

Hi, I am trying to read in a json file and populate my mongoDB with the rows called ependencies.it keeps giving me and error. I have tried insert, insert_one &insert_many to no avail.

The following is the error i get

```
    File "database.py", line 43, in <module>
    collection.insert_one(i)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 684, in insert_one
    common.validate_is_document_type("document", document)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 453, in validate_is_document_type
    "collections.MutableMapping" % (option,))
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database.py", line 43, in <module>
    collection.insert_one(i)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 684, in insert_one
    common.validate_is_document_type("document", document)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 453, in validate_is_document_type
    "collections.MutableMapping" % (option,))
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

The json file is a list of node dependencies. i ran the command npm list on a node project. Can anybody help Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the data that you are iterating over look like?

Comment: "name": "express-ibm",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "problems": [
    "missing: serve-favicon@~2.4.5, required by express-ibm@0.0.0"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "async": {
      "version": "2.6.1",
      "from": "async",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-2.6.1.tgz"
    },
    "body-parser": {
      "version": "1.18.3",
      "from": "body-parser@1.18.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser/-/body-parser-1.18.3.tgz"
    },
    "cookie-parser": {
      "version": "1.4.3",
      "from": "cookie-parser@~1.4.

Comment: ok, `dependencies` is a `dict`, which means `for i in dependencies` will return the `keys`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you Expalin a bit more ? I am lost.

Comment: I put it in an answer, a bit long for a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data in `dependencies` is a `dictionary`. This means when you iterate over it, you will get strings (which are the keys in this case).

An example would be like so:

```
my_entry = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

for i in myentry:
    print(i)

# will print 'a' then 'b', not 1 then 2
```

I'm assuming each dependency is a key, and you want to insert the value. So

```
# dictionary.values() will give you just the values
for v in parsed['dependencies'].values():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        collection.insert_one(v)
    else:
        raise ValueError("object is not dictionary")
```

Mongo will only take `json` or `bson` entries, which are like dictionaries. When you pass `keys`, you are trying to insert objects of type `string`, which it doesn't support